# Развернуть свернутое в трей приложение

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mutex

Готов утонуть в минусах, но не знаю,как развернуть свернутое приложение в трей по кнопке. Подскажите пожалуйста.
На всякий случай код кнопки, которая сворачивает

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Код Program.cs

```
static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "{8F6F0AC4-B9A1-45fd-A8CF-72F04E6BDE8F}");
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, true))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FormLogin());
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Программа уже запущенна. Возможно, она свернута.");

        }
    }
```

Я пробовал все варианты, которые находил в сети. Один из них даже разворачивал свернутую программу в панели задач, но не разворачивал из трея.

У меня получается сначала запускается форма Логина. Она имет одну кнопку управления окном - закрыть. А вот после логина, попадаем на другую форму. И вот уже там, есть кнопка закрыть и кнопка свернуть, код которой, был выше. Системные кнопки "свернуть, расширить, закрыть" отключены.

Что нужно дописать в Program.cs, чтобы он разворачивал? Отслеживать по имени окна, я бы не хотел. Не слишком и надежно.

Comment: Нужно слать сообщение тем или иным способом. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1777704/5045688 / Ещё можно попробовать WindowsFormsApplicationBase. [тыц](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5bcfc8a-bf69-4bbc-923d-f30f9ecf5f64/single-instance-application?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Ссылки на ответы из 2008го это сильно) НО. Со второй ссылкой я не разобрался, но вот первая... Человек, который ответил ниже вашего выделенного сообщения, с ником chitza, сделал неплохую реализацию. Она вроде действительно работает и возвращает окно из трея. Но если оно просто свернуто, то ничего не происходит. Ему это вроде как указали и он обещал исправить. Но к сожалению, он так и не отредачил сообщение. Надеюсь он жив и он просто забыл. Спасибо Вам, Александр. Помогли

Comment: Вообще, не обязательно завязываться на оконные сообщения. Можно использовать любой способ [межпроцессного взаимодействия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межпроцессное_взаимодействие). Ещё [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications). Например, именованные каналы (named pipes).